# Como definir uma propriedade CSS com nome dinâmico via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso usar o valor de uma string pra mudar uma propriedade CSS de um elemento.

Já tentei fazer isto, mas não funcionou:

```js
function funciona(nome, valor, id){
  id.style.nome = valor;
}

function changecolor(){
  var id = document.getElementById('teste');
  var nomeProp = "background-color";
  var valorprop = "green";
  funciona(nomeProp, valorprop, id);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="cursor:pointer; color:pink;" onclick="changecolor();"> este é um teste </h1>
<div id="teste" style="background-color:red; width:200px; height:170px;"> </div>
```

Comment: `id` não é uma string reservada? acho que vc não pode usa-la como nome de. variável...

Comment: @hugocsl, `id` é válido. Não faz parte da lista de [palavras reservadas](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) do JavaScript.

Comment: Você está tentando setar uma propriedade CSS `nome` que não existe. Precisaria ser `id.style[nome]`. OBS: a variável `id` está mal nomeada, ela não contém o ID de um elemento, e sim o próprio elemento.

Comment: @LuizFelipe massa! Eu achava que poderia ser, mas não tinha certeza. Valeu a dica!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [`setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty), disponível no objeto `Element.style`. Por exemplo:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

function changeCSS() {
  const propName = 'background-color';
  const propValue = 'blue';
  
  body.style.setProperty(propName, propValue);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeCSS();">Mudar CSS</button>
```

---

Leia [Aceder às propriedades em JavaScript: notação de ponto ou colchetes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/463602/69296) para entender porque o código da pergunta não funcionou. Em resumo, a notação de ponto não funciona de forma dinâmica.

Portanto, conforme a resposta linkada aponta, uma outra opção para esse tipo de situação é utilizar, ao invés do ponto, a notação de colchetes – que aceita strings "dinâmicas" como chaves de propriedade.

Mas note que, nesse caso, você terá que utilizar o nome da propriedade em seu formato `camelCase` ao invés de `dash-case`, uam vez que o objeto `Element.style` possui as propriedades CSS seguindo a convenção `camelCase`. Então, ao invés de `"background-color"`, você teria a chave `"backgroundColor"`.

Análogo ao exemplo acima, fica assim:

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');

function changeCSS() {
  // Note que o nome agora foi escrito em camelCase:
  const propName = 'backgroundColor';
  const propValue = 'blue';
  
  body.style[propName] = propValue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeCSS();">Mudar CSS</button>
```

É ideal fazer uma verificação se o nome da propriedade é válido antes de fazer esse último tipo de definição. Mas omiti essa parte visando brevidade.

Answer (score 1):

Se for apenas um tipo de propriedade, você pode usar o próprio atributo style, que contém todos os valores CSS, tanto para consulta, quanto para alteração:

```js
const color = "blue";
element.style.backgroundColor = color;
```